# "clearAll" button in filter editor not working properly in remote filter mode

Tags: reactjs, react-data-grid

I'm having a problem with filtering in react data grid. When i change the remoteFilter = {true} for server-side filtering. The filter editor does not let me to handle clear and clearAll buttons. Also, it doesn't work properly in remote filter mode. For example:
when i search string and click clearAll it only removes the last letter/number. It's not removing all of the string.

In addition, i tried to remove this button but there is no way to control it. How can i fix or remove it?

i am using this npm package:
@inovua/reactdatagrid-community

[image]

Comment: Please share reproducible example or code to show how you're implementing it.

Comment: Here is an example of my repo https://github.com/msanli220/reactDataGrid-remoteFilterMode